# How keras manages weights of convolutional layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working with the MNIST data set and I am using keras to train a convolutional neural network.
There is something about the weight matrices that I do not understand.

The input layer has 28x28=784 neurons. Then I use:

```
Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(7,7),stride=(3,3),use_bias=False)
Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(5,5),stride=(2,2),use_bias=False)
Flatten()
Dense(200,use_bias=False)
Dense(150,use_bias=False)
Dense(10,use_bias=False,softmax)
```

After I train the model and put W = model.get_weights(), I print W[i].shape for each i and obtain:

```
(7,7,1,32)
(5,5,32,64)
(256,200)
(200,150)
(150,10)
```

As far as I understand, this means that for the first hidden layer there are 32 images of 8x8=64 (since (28-7)/3+1=8) and therefore there are 64x32=2048 neurons in the first hidden layer.

The next part is the one that confuses me. Since the next convolution has kernel size (5,5) and stride (2,2) and uses 64 filters, does this means that we apply 64 convolutions to each 8x8 image obtained in the first hidden layer? That will give 64x32=2048 images of size 2x2 and there will be 2048x4=8192 neurons in the second hidden layer. But the weight matrix of the next layer is of shape (256,200). Shouldn't it be of shape (8192,200)?  What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this explanation will helpful.
General formula for calculate the output feature is this

```
N_out = ([N_input + 2*padding - kernal_size]/stride) + 1
```

For first conv layer

```
N_out = ([28 + 2(0) - 7])/3)+1
N_out = 8
```

you get 8x8 image with 32 filters

For second conv layer

```
N_out = ([8 + 2(0) - 5])/2)+1
N_out = 2.5
```

as you can see output size is 2.5,since you are not specified padding,tensorflow use default padding as "VALID".[check this link for source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L493-L527).

Now lets see what will happen if you use valid padding over 8x8 image with 5X5 kernal with stride 2.
this is the ascii art

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
|_______|          <--- 1 st window
    |_______|      <--- 2 nd window
        |________  <--- 3rd window will drop(since valid padding)
```

So you endup with 2x2 image with 64 channels after 2nd layer,which is 256.

for example,

```
from keras import layers

m = Sequential()
m.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(7,7),strides=(3,3),use_bias=False,input_shape=(28,28,1)))
m.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(5,5),strides=(2,2),use_bias=False))
m.add(Flatten())
m.add(Dense(200,use_bias=False))
m.add(Dense(150,use_bias=False))
m.add(Dense(10,use_bias=False,activation='softmax'))

for layer in m.layers: 
    print(layer.output_shape)
```

output

```
(None, 8, 8, 32)
(None, 2, 2, 64)
(None, 256)
(None, 200)
(None, 150)
(None, 10)
```

Comment: Then what does (5,5,32,64) for the shape of weights means?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what are the outputs of the model.get_weights() returns.but if you loop over layers and print output_shape like this,you will get the idea  `from keras import layers` `for layer in m.layers: 
    print(layer.output_shape)`

Comment: I still feel that there is something funny happenings between the two convolutional layers that I do not fully understand. I mean, from the first conv2d you get 32 images of size 8x8. The second conv2d says there are 64 filters, but to what exactly are those 64 filters applied? To each one of the 32 images of 8x8? Does it form a unique big image with the 32 images of 8x8 to which it applies the 64 filters? I want to know the neural network architecture in this case and I only can construct before the second conv2d and after it, but right at it I don't see what is happening.

Comment: So the input layer has 784 neurons, the second one has 32x8x8 neurons, I don't see how to determine the neurons for the third layer and to visualize the weights between this layer and the ones around it.

Comment: understanding architecture is a different topic you should do some research. check these links for your reference https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180850/how-are-filters-and-activation-maps-connected-in-convolutional-neural-networks https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365307/connection-between-filters-and-feature-map-in-cnn